# loading intital ramdisk freezes in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel, freeze

So I was trying to change my lockscreen(GDM) theme, but after executing these codes;-`

```
sudo cp /usr/share/gnome-share/theme/ubuntu.bak /usr/share/gnome-share/theme/ubuntu.css
sudo cp ubuntu.css /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme cp SetAsWallpaper ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts
sudo chmod 777 /usr/share/backgrounds
```

After this when I tried to visulise the changes by going to the lockscreen,I could see that was nothing changed, so I tried restarting the system but the screen freezed at purple color,I then tried using "advance options for ubuntu" and booting into the latest system image but again the screen freezed at "loading intial ramdisk".After some experimenting I'm able to login to my system but only with kernel "linux 5.0.0-37-generic",that too in advance options,I'm unable to boot into my computer normally, if there is any way fixing this please help
P.S:- I'm a beginner in linux so I was just following a youtube video here's the link to that video in case it helps [The process starts at 11:40](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfsKwzElxQg)